# Rendering 2 views using single collection in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

I am facing issue while rendering 2 views using single collection in Backbone.
In my app, there is a Main View, in which I am initializing Items Collection, so it can be accessible to all children views.
There is an Item View, which is being used to render single item in both the Views (Quick and normal) whenever any item is added to the collection.
Quick View has to be render for all the Routes of the App. Whereas, Normal view will rendered only domain/checkout route called. Domain/checkout can be called in 2 ways:

1. Click on checkout button – in this case, both are in sync and working fine.
2. Access domain/checkout Path directly – in this case, Quick and Normal views are not in sync.

// Main View

```
var mainView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: 'body',
    template: {
        header: Handlebars.compile(headerTemplate),
        mainNav: Handlebars.compile(mainNavtemplate),
        footer: Handlebars.compile(footerTemplate)
    },
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this);
        AW.collection.bag = new bagCollection();
        AW.collection.bag.fetch({reset:true});
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        this.loadSubView('bagQV');
    }
});
```

// Quick View

```
var bagQuickView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName:    'div',
    id:         'myBagQV',
    template:   Handlebars.compile(bagQuickViewTemplate),
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this);
        //this.collection.fetch({reset:true});
        //this.collection.bind("reset", _.bind(this.render, this));
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.addItem);
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
    },
    render: function() {
        if($('#myBagQV').length == 0) {
            this.$el.html(this.template());
            $('body').append(this.el);
        }
        this.addAllItems();
        return this;
    }
});
```

// Normal View

```
var bagView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName:    'div',
    id:         'myBag',
    template:   Handlebars.compile(checkoutBagTemplate),
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this);
        //this.collection.fetch({reset:true});
        //this.collection.bind("reset", _.bind(this.render, this));
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.addItem);
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        $('#checkoutContainer #details').append(this.el);
        this.addAllItems();
        return this;
    }
});
```

Comment: an jsfiddle will help understand it better

Comment: HI Ravi, Actually code is splitted into multiple files, so its not easy to paste on jsfiddle. If you want, i can given you more details

Comment: I am not sure what issue you are having? Why are you having problems sharing a collection between views?

Comment: Please check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197927/multiple-views-and-sub-views-with-1-collection-in-backbone?noredirect=1#comment28429274_19197927) , where I explained my issue in detail